# How to save and restore zoom positon in eclipse IDE ViewPart?

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse IDE `ViewPart`.

How to save and restore zoom position in eclipse IDE `ViewPart`?

In left side navigation we have some list which opens editors. Editor part(device image) we have zoom position 125 to 400 % . While closing editor zoom percentage is 200 , I need to save this zoom position for this part under particular list id . While opening the same list id it display with last zoom position.

```
public class name extends ViewPart
{
    public void init(final IViewSite site) throws PartInitException
    {     
        public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference ref) {//do some stuff}

        public void partclosed(IWorkbenchPartReference ref) {//do some stuff}    
    }
}
```

I need to save and restore zoom position when `vViewPart` close and opening . Not on workbench close and opening time.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right place as far as what to do. The usual way to save this stuff is using the IMemento interface. You can search for references to that and you will see many examples.

Comment: `IMemento` is used for storing state over a session restart, it won't be called in general open/close.  But you can extend your `part#dispose()` method to save state in your plugin location, and read it back in your `init(*)`.

Comment: Thanks Paul .Could you please tell some useful information link whenever part get close and open (save and restore information),so that i will follow it.